# Coverting this python script to C#

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to convert the following python extract to C

```
tvip = "192.168.0.3"
myip = "192.168.0.7"
mymac = "00-0c-29-3e-b1-4f"
appstring = "iphone..iapp.samsung"
tvappstring = "iphone.UE55C8000.iapp.samsung"
remotename = "Python Samsung Remote" 

ipencoded = base64.b64encode(myip)
macencoded = base64.b64encode(mymac)
messagepart1 = chr(0x64) + chr(0x00) + chr(len(ipencoded)) \
+ chr(0x00) + ipencoded + chr(len(macencoded)) + chr(0x00) \
+ macencoded + chr(len(base64.b64encode(remotename))) + chr(0x00) \
+ base64.b64encode(remotename)
part1 = chr(0x00) + chr(len(appstring)) + chr(0x00) + appstring \
+ chr(len(messagepart1)) + chr(0x00) + messagepart1
```

I don't actually know what `messagepart1` actually represents in terms of datastructure.

Here is my attempt:

```
var myip_e = myip.ToBase64();
var mymac_e = mymac.ToBase64();

var m1 = (char)0x64 + (char)0x00 + (char)myip_e.Length + (char)0x00 + myip_e + 
    (char)mymac_e.Length + (char)0x00 + mymac_e + (char)remotename.ToBase64().Length + (char)0x00 +remotename.ToBase64();
var p1 = (char)0x00 + (char)appstring.Length + (char)0x00 + appstring + (char)m1.Length + (char)0x00 + m1;
//var b1 = p1.GetBytes(); // this is to write to the socket.

public static string ToBase64(this string source)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(source.GetBytes());
}

public static byte[] GetBytes(this string source)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[source.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(source.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

The way I am comparing is that I am printing both to console, expecting them to be the same if correct - obviously I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What `chr(0x64) + chr(0x00)` means in Python?  It seems `char(0x64) + char(0x00)` is not the proper translation (adds two `char` values [signed 16bit integer], and the result is 0x64).

Comment: @wdosanjos: In Python, characters are simply strings of length 1, and the `+` operator can be used to concatenate two strings. So, as you correctly guessed, it does something else that the C# program: It creates a string containing the letter `d` and a NUL byte.

Comment: @wdosanjos In any case it would have been much clearer if instead of `chr(0x64) + chr(0x00)` the code used `'\x64\x00'` or `\x64\0` (by the way: in Python there is *no* difference between `'` and `"`. By convention `"` is used when writing "human-readable" messages while `'` is used for strings used only by the program itself.)

Comment: Python is **not** loosely typed. Your `messagepart1` is a *string. In fact *all* identifiers in that code refer to *strings*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after consideration of the comments, I now have some working code. Here are the changes

```
        var builderM1 = new StringBuilder();
        builderM1.Append((char)0x64);
        builderM1.Append((char)0x00);
        builderM1.Append((char)myip_e.Length);
        builderM1.Append((char)0x00);
        builderM1.Append(myip_e);
        builderM1.Append((char)mymac_e.Length);
        builderM1.Append((char)0x00);
        builderM1.Append(mymac_e);
        builderM1.Append((char)remotename.ToBase64().Length);
        builderM1.Append((char)0x00);
        builderM1.Append(remotename.ToBase64());

        var m1 = builderM1.ToString();

        var builderP1 = new StringBuilder();
        builderP1.Append((char)(0x00));
        builderP1.Append((char)appstring.Length);
        builderP1.Append((char)(0x00));
        builderP1.Append(appstring);
        builderP1.Append((char)m1.Length);
        builderP1.Append((char)(0x00));
        builderP1.Append(m1);

        Console.WriteLine(builderP1.ToString());

public static string ToBase64(this string source)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(source));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at SharpDevelop, they support C# and IronPython and there are some converters between different languages in this IDE. 
http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Features.aspx 
Not sure, that It completly solve your issue, but may be it help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution based on @Bakuriu's comments:

```
    var m1 = string.Format("\x64\x00{0}\x00{1}{2}\x00{3}{4}\x00{5}", 
                (char)myip_e.Length, myip_e, (char)mymac_e.Length, mymac_e, 
                (char)remotename.ToBase64().Length, remotename.ToBase64());

    var p1 = string.Format("\x00{0}\x00{1}{2}\x00{3}", 
                (char)appstring.Length, appstring, (char)m1.Length, m1);
```